# Expo keeps restarting when user navigate to another screen or is navigated

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

## Intro

I am quite new to react-native, and I was trying to create a drawer menu for my first mobile app, and [it was working up to this commit](https://github.com/kasir-barati/solo-trainee/commit/9001c96aacd955e32974699cecab024f5a4c0772) but then after that it was crashing when I was navigating to another screen manually or programmatically.

## What I've tried

1. So I installed the web version to check the console and see what is wrong and browser was showing this alert to me: [image]
2. I tried to log the step and see where it is crashing and it turns out that it is when it tries to execute this code: `navigation.navigate('Home');`

## Current situation

Now I am at a total lost since all the packages are upgraded to the latest version and still I cannot figure it out what is happening. Here is [the repo](https://github.com/kasir-barati/solo-trainee) to reproduce this issue.

### More info

I am using `expo`, `@react-navigation/drawer`, `@react-navigation/native`, and `@react-navigation/native-stack`. I firmly believe something is wrong with the library that I am using and that is why I opened [this issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11815) too